# Tool to recover & repair a corrupted *.MDB database (Access)

Tags: ms-access, corruption

Over the years I have seen many errors on corrupted Access *.MDB files.
I do not use Access as frontend, just as backend to store data Tables.
I already use the best practices: normalization, close the database connection ASAP, etc.

I was wondering if somebody knew which the best commercial tool to recover data from a corrupted MDB file is. (I need a tool, not a service).

I have seen AccessFix, Access Recovery, Advanced Access Repair.
Have you used any of these tools?
Any winner? Any recommendation? Any advice?

Thanks,
Jag

P.S. I know I shouldn’t be using an Access backend on a concurrent user & network environment, but there is nothing I can do right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I started professional Access development in 1996, I have only once had a corrupted MDB that required anything other than the built-in compact/repair tools. In that case, I used [Peter Miller's PKSolutions](http://pksolutions.com/t4.htm). And in that one case, the corruption was my fault -- I killed the Access process while it was running a large update.

Comment: I think I can add a few years to that, and though I would not claim to be a professional developer, I, too, have only seen one very badly damaged mdb, and that was on a badly damaged computer, and the data was recoverable.

Comment: I didn't was this question to be a commercial... so I will just say that the 3 products work great. AAR is the best at recovering data. And I found that the other two work great at recovering modules and stuff I didn't need since I just use Access as a backend.

Comment: By the way... I got great customer support from AAR and AccessFIX. I didn't get an answer from Access Recovery. And I didn't contact PKSolutions since I wanted a tool, not a service. Thanks anyway David, I'll mark this “as the answer” since I wanted a comment/suggestion and not an absolute truth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stellar access database repair software which provides you free evaluation of software to check the reliability of software.

Comment: You should declare your affiliation with the product in your answer, rather than just having it in your profile. But fair play that you've connected yourself with the product there at least.

Comment: I think it is scummy to just put the affiliation in the profile, since people have to look there to see that the recommendation is not unbiased. This answer should be edited to include that information explicitly, it seems to me, particularly given the history here, where the first post by this person told a series of lies in order to recommend the product.